# return not working in service

Tags: grails, groovy

I am getting a wierd problem and i am stuck on it for atleast 4 hours now. Actually i had written my code in a controller for testing but when i have moved the code to service i am getting a strange behaviour that the methods in service are not returning or may be methods that are calling them in the service only are not receiving .

```
class FacebookService implements InitializingBean, GroovyInterceptable {
def getUserLikes(def at){
List<String> listOfUrls = []
    String basicFbUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/"
    String likeUrl = basicFbUrl + "me/likes?access_token=${at}"
    URL url = new URL(likeUrl)
    String jsonResponse = getResponseFromUrl(url)
    println "JSON RESPONSE IS ${jsonResponse}" // this is showing null
}

String getResponseFromUrl() {
  String something

  String resp = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    try {
        int respCode = conn.responseCode
        if (respCode == 400) {
            log.error("COULD NOT MAKE CONNECTION")
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));
            def jsonResp = JSON.parse(br.text)
        } else {
            resp = conn.getInputStream().getText()
        }
    } finally {
        conn.disconnect()
    }

    println("RETURNIG RESPONSE ${resp}") // This returns me a map as expected 

    return resp; 
}
```

Dont know where does resp goes ?? any suggestions please ??
OK i know the culprit , i am posting the code of invokeMethod

```
def invokeMethod(String name, args){
    System.out.println("IN INVOKE METHOD NAME ${name}")
    if(facebookPalsCache==null)
        facebookPalsCache = new FacebookPalsCache(1000)
    System.out.println("time before ${name} called: ${new Date()}")

    //Get the method that was originally called.
    def calledMethod = metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args)
    System.out.println("CALLED METHOD IS ${calledMethod}")

    //The "?" operator first checks to see that the "calledMethod" is not
    //null (i.e. it exists).
    if(name.equals("getFriends")){
        println "getFriends..."
        def session = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSession()
        def friends = facebookPalsCache.get(session.facebook.uid)
        if(!friends){
            def getFriends = facebookGraphService.invokeMethod (name, args)
            println "Saving FBFRIENDS in CACHE"
            facebookPalsCache.put(session.facebook.uid, getFriends)
            return getFriends
        }
        else return friends
    }

    else {
        if(calledMethod){
            System.out.println("IN IF AND INVOKING METHOD ${calledMethod}")
            calledMethod.invoke(this, args)
        }
        else {
            return facebookGraphService.invokeMethod(name, args)
        }
    }
    System.out.println "RETURNING FROM INVOKE METHOD FOR NAME ${name}"
    System.out.println("time after ${name} called: ${new Date()}\n")
}
```

OK SOMETHING IS WRONG ABOVE I DONT KNOW WHAT CAN ANYONE PLEASE HELP ??

Comment: Can you post the actual code?

Comment: You must have something else named `methodB` in the visibility scope. A closure, a variable, whatever. +1 for actual code.

Comment: hi victor , tim : sorry for late response but there;s nothing as such.. just that from a UtilController i am calling the service methodA and from that methodA in the service i am calling another method which is methodB . Now all is well till methodB returns something , its not available in methodA , but if i write the methodB in UtilController , i get the return value.. I thought it had something to do with my service since it implements InitializingBean, GroovyInterceptable

Comment: Maybe your interceptor is messing up the return value?

Comment: i have shared my code now , maybe someone can throw some light on it now ????

Comment: tim_yates , Victor Sergienko , Gustavo Giraldez i have posted the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for `invokeMethod` and the service don't seem to be the same unless there's a separate `FacebookGraphService`. Assuming that's the case, then the `resp` is being caught in the part of your `invokeMethod` that's inside the `if (calledMethod) {` block, but since it's not the last line of the method it's not being returned from the call to `invokeMethod` and therefore is being gobbled up.

Try adding a return to `calledMethod.invoke(this, args)`:

```
    if(calledMethod){
        System.out.println("IN IF AND INVOKING METHOD ${calledMethod}")
        return calledMethod.invoke(this, args)
    }
```